# Custom Admin Email Subject for Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, child-theming

I would like the Email Subject line for the admin email to change based on the product category.
I've looked at ALL similar stack overflow questions and NONE of them work for WooCommerece 3.8.0
(see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49276342/change-woocommerce-email-subject-if-order-have-this-specific-category) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55686844/add-the-product-name-to-the-email-subject-in-woocommerce)).

What I have is this

```
function custom_admin_email_subject( $subject, $order ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    foreach($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ){
        if ( has_term( 'Category 1 Name', 'product_cat' , $item->get_product_id() ) ) { 
            break;
            $subject = sprintf( 'Category 1 Email Subject Line' );
        }
    } 
    return $subject;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_email_subject_new_order', 'custom_admin_email_subject', 1, 2);
```

My code simply returns the default email subject line for new orders (which is set in woocommerce/settings/email). 
I can't figure out why my function does not recognize category names.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

I am placing this code in my child-theme/functions.php file
I am running WooCommerce 3.8.0 and WordPress 5.3

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your `if condition`. You should break the execution of `foreach` loop when product has term, only after setting the value in `$subject` variable. Rewrite your `if condition` as following. Have tested this and works :)

```
if( has_term( 'Category 1 Name', 'product_cat' , $item->get_product_id() ) ){ 
    $subject = sprintf( 'Hoodies Email Subject Line' );
    break;
}
```

Comment: Sadly,  it didn't work. For some reason it is not overriding the default email subject line
This is what I now have `function custom_admin_email_subject( $subject, $order ){
    global $woocommerce;
    $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);
    foreach($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ){
        if( has_term( 'woo-cat-slug', 'product_cat' , $item->get_product_id() ) ){ 
            $subject = sprintf( 'Custom Email Subject Line' );
            break;
            }
        } 
    return $subject;
}`
Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: The above code should work. Double check the slug name `woo-cat-slug` in your code. Confirm whether `woo-cat-slug` is the slug of the product category